# How to avoid GROUP BY clause in Informix SQL

Tags: sql, informix

I have a query which has many group by clause, and it's taking hours to retrieve data from tables. Is there a way to avoid this?
Query has huge group by and when I observe the query plan I can see scan(index scan), joins taking too long.

Comment: You need to at least include some information about your data set and an example query.

Comment: As you were told, we need more information than this to be able to help you (an MCVE - [MCVE]). At the moment, it is unlikely that your problem is Informix-specific, but it is good to include the DBMS in the question. Please identify which version you're using; there might be some differences, especially if you're using an archaic version of Informix. Also include outline schemas of the tables you need to work on, the primary and foreign key relationships between them, and preferably a few sample rows of data from each table, plus the desired result for the sample data; your query and result.

Comment: Read about table indexing and [explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html)

Comment: Ouch!  The massive use of NVL is indicative of schema design problems, in my view.  The use of 26-columns in the GROUP BY clause is another problem indicator.  The absence of outline schemas doesn't make your query any easier to understand, and the use of the old-style notations in the FROM clause, not to mention the Informix-specific OUTER notation, make it harder to understand.  I'd be tolerably sure you should have the 4 SUM operations in a sub-query, the result of which is joined to the rest.  But I'm not prepared to put the effort into generating your schema or minimal sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Which Informix version and edition are you using?

Can you provide the query plan?

Without the group by how many rows would be returned?

I would denormalize the data.

Also why

```
(
                SELECT  MIN(l.customer_id) customer_id,
                        h.cust_key              
                FROM    lenstore_custs l,
                        c_head h
                WHERE   l.c_rec_key = h.c_rec_key
                GROUP   BY 2
            ) l,
```

How many rows in lenstore_custs and c_head?

Perhaps store in the min cust_id in the c_head table to avoid the need for a join and group by each time.

Also

```
    (
        SELECT  MAX(m.unit_mes_desc)
        FROM    art_mast m,
                art_unit_mes u,
                inv_detail i
        WHERE   i.visit_key = v.visit_key
        AND     i.item_type = "J"
        AND     i.item_no = u.ean11
        AND     u.article_number = m.article_number
    ) cl_info
```

why the max desc, max on a desc column sounds wrong!

Also

```
NVL(c.contact_fp_qty + c.contact_sp_qty,0)
```

You do realize that if EITHER value is NULL the the + will evaluate to NULL and the result will be 0. You probably need to NVL,0 each column and add them together.

I would change the data model perhaps with default 0 values on the columns as well such that the value 0 is stored is columns which are not relevant rather than null to aid summing of columns. If you really need to know if a value was null then add a indicator column to show the value is null.